# How do I call from a dataset and have it compare two different data points in python?

Tags: python, compare

I'm not very good with python... I have a data set of NBA players and their stats, and I need to create a code where it allows the user to input any player from the data set, and then it will tell the user who would be most likely to win in a 1v1 situation. The way it would do this is if one of the players has higher stats in 4 out of the 6 categories I put (Field goal %, 3 point shots made, rebounds per game, steals per game, blocks per game, and points per game), then they would win. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? so far this is all the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
df = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSTbHMm7RQOxOj6yl17g7MLfCBFghAACUie0k3HLB_ja9E0t0HpENl4ydN4b58UdCCiBTB9rvj0zy-O/pub?output=csv")
df.head()
```

Comment: Add some sample data and the intended result.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We need to know, *at a minimum*: 1) what code you are trying to use; 2) what you think it means to "call from" a dataset; 3) what kind of "comparison" you want to do; 4) what a "data point" looks like for you in your data; 5) what happens when you try to use your code; 6) what you want to happen instead and how that is different. We *don't* need to know that you aren't very good with python, partly because we might have guessed but mostly because knowing that *does not help solve the problem*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas library to access the values in the dataset which you wanted to use as a criterion to predict the win. You should make a function and in it apply your way.

```
#Index-based selection¶
#Pandas indexing works in one of two paradigms. The first is index-based selection: selecting data based on its numerical position in the data. iloc follows this paradigm.
#To select the first row of data in a DataFrame, we may use the following:

df.iloc[0]
#to get a column
df.iloc[:, 0]
df.iloc[[0, 1, 2], 0]
#Label-based selection
#The second paradigm for attribute selection is the one followed by the loc operator: label-based selection. In this paradigm, it's the data index value, not its position, which matters.
#For example, to get the first entry in reviews, we would now do the following:
df.loc[0, 'country']
df.loc[:, ['taster_name', 'taster_twitter_handle', 'points']]
cols=['dc','adfa','fas']
indiecs-[0,1,10,14]
df.loc[indiecs,cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a few extras in there, but basically,

1. You need to somehow get the inputs of the 2 players you want.
2. Filter out your dataframe to get those particular player stats
3. Compare those stats and score them in some way
4. Sum up the scores for each category/colum
5. Print out the results

**Code:**

```
#pip install fuzzywuzzy
#pip install choice

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import choice


df = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSTbHMm7RQOxOj6yl17g7MLfCBFghAACUie0k3HLB_ja9E0t0HpENl4ydN4b58UdCCiBTB9rvj0zy-O/pub?output=csv")
choices = list(df['PLAYER'])

def select_player(choices, player_no):
    player = input('Type player %s: ' %player_no)
    if 100 not in [x[1] for x in process.extract(player, choices, limit=5)]:
        print('Which player did you mean?')
        player = choice.Menu([x[0] for x in process.extract(player, choices, limit=5)]).ask()
    else:
        player = process.extract(player, choices, limit=5)[0][0]
    print('You selected: %s' %player)
    return player


def play_game(player_1, player_2):    
    player_1_stats = df[df['PLAYER'] == player_1]
    player_2_stats = df[df['PLAYER'] == player_2]
    
    score = player_1_stats.append(player_2_stats).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    num_cols = list(score.select_dtypes('number').columns)
    for col in num_cols:
        winning_score = score[col].max()
        score[col] = np.where(score[col] == winning_score, 1,0)
    score['Total'] = score[num_cols].sum(axis=1)
    
    print(score[['PLAYER','Total']])
    
player_1 = select_player(choices, 1)
player_2 = select_player(choices, 2)

play_game(player_1, player_2)
```

**Output:**

```
Type player 1: james harden
You selected: James Harden

Type player 2: Jim Butler
Which player did you mean?
Make a choice:
 0: Jimmy Butler
 1: Ben Simmons
 2: Devin Booker

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 0

You selected: Jimmy Butler

          PLAYER  Total
0  James Harden      4
1  Jimmy Butler      3
```